# Alternate use cases for DHIS2

Tags: java, tomcat, dhis-2

Good day all.

Has anybody used DHIS2 for alternate cases, such as alien plant invasion research, and soil erosion on coastlines research.

Please can somebody confirm as well, if DHIS supports image capture in the field through the android app. - as I would like to use this platform for the above 2 cases mentioned.

Assistance is much appreciated for my questions.

Implementing and installing this

Answer (score 1):

DHIS2 can be adapted for a vast range of use cases. The main thing that will guide you in deciding whether DHIS2 is the correct type of software to use is the location or geographical context where your data will be anchored. In DHIS2, this is referred to as "Organisation Unit". In the health domain, this is the health facilities and this organisational units can be structured hierarchically, starting from the lowest health facility to, say, the whole district that has multiple health facilities. In your case, the organisation unit can be the different labs where your research is conducted from.

Yes the DHIS2 Capture Android app can capture images and upload them to your server on the latest updates of DHIS2 software. The [DHIS2 Capture documentation](https://docs.dhis2.org/master/en/android-app/html/dhis2_android_capture_app_full.html) describes what is possible with the app.